# How to run Spock tests with Gradle, Junit and Spock in Vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, groovy, junit

I am trying to make a transition from Intellij to vscode at work. At the moment, we have tests written in Groovy (utilizing the Spock framework), Gradle as the build tool, and Junit as the runner.

After installing all the relevant extensions (Test Runner for Java, Jave, and Gradle) and configure the launch.json file , I am still not able to run the tests using vscode.

The error I am getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class spock.TestSpec
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spock.TestSpec
```

---

My launch.json looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "mainClass": "spock.TestSpec",
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "classPaths": [
                "tester.test"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Some info about my system:

```
$ java -version

openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16.1+1 (build 11.0.16.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.16.1+1 (build 11.0.16.1+1, mixed mode)
```

---

```
$ where java

/usr/bin/java
```

---

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.16.1 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.16.1+1)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.6 x86_64
```

---

The test I want to run is in:

```
src/test/groovy/spock/TestSpec.groovy
```

---

TestSpec.groovy

```
package spock

import base.BaseSpec

class TestSpec{

    def "SimpleTest"() {
        expect:
        name.size() == length

        where:
        name     | length
        "Spock"  | 5
        "Kirk"   | 4
        "Scotty" | 6
    }
```

---

gradle.properties

```
ar_root=tmp
download_location=snapshot
cloudfront_enabled=false
ar_version=*master*
test_scope=quick
test_part=1
Database = "postgresql"
ar_contextUrl=https://se.jd.io/ar
docker_url=http://localhost:4243/
containerized=true

#Credentials for admin user to run the test
test_ar_user=admin
test_ar_password=password

####### PUPPET versions #######
puppet_version.milestone=6.0.9
```

---

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'federated-repository-tester'
```

---

build.gradle

```
import org.jf.qa.common.CommonEnums
import tasks.StartarTask
import tasks.CollectLogsTask
import tasks.DeleteContainersTask
import org.jf.qa.gradle.tasks.ReportPortalTask
import org.jf.qa.common.VersionUtil
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}
apply from: 'gradle/common.gradle'

// ar version set for all nodes
def ar_version = getProp("ar_version")
def pr1_ar_version = getProp("pr1_version")
def pr2_ar_version = getProp("pr2_version")
def ha_ar_version = getProp("ha_version")
def test_scope = getProp("test_scope")
String database = getProp("database")
def ar_type = CommonEnums.atp.PRO.toString()

def arAdminPassword = project.hasProperty("ar_admin_password") ? ar_admin_password : System.getenv("ar_admin_password")

def dockerUrl = project.hasProperty("DOCKER_URL") ? DOCKER_URL : "http://localhost:4243/"

def containerized = containerized

// first ar node properties
def arpr1_url = project.hasProperty("arpr1_url") ? project.property("arpr1_url") : null

// second ar node properties
def arpr2_url = project.hasProperty("arpr2_url") ? project.property("arpr2_url") : null

// ha-primary ar node properties
def arHaMaster_url = project.hasProperty("arHaMaster_url") ? project.property("arHaMaster_url") : null

// ha-secondary ar node properties
def arHaSlave_url = project.hasProperty("arHaSlave_url") ? project.property("arHaSlave_url") : null

// ar nginx properties
def arNginx_url = project.hasProperty("arNginx_url") ? project.property("arNginx_url") :null

def dockerRegistry = project.hasProperty("DOCKER_REGISTRY") ? DOCKER_REGISTRY : "qa.jf.io"
def federationApproach = project.hasProperty("federation_approach") ? project.property("federation_approach") : null
def build_number = project.hasProperty("build_number") ? project.property("build_number") : ""
def branch_name = project.hasProperty("branch_name") ? project.property("branch_name") : ""
def ci_type = project.hasProperty("ci_type") ? project.property("ci_type") : "jenkins"
def build_url = project.hasProperty("build_url") ? project.property("build_url") : ""
boolean send_report = Boolean.parseBoolean(getProp("send_report") ?: "false")
String spec = project.hasProperty("Spec") ? project.property("Spec") : ""

ext {
    // arNames, Containers and Urls
    arpr1_container = null
    arpr1_url

    arpr2_container = null
    arpr2_url

    arHaMaster_container = null
    arHaMaster_url

    arHaSlave_container = null
    arHaSlave_url

    arNginx_container = null
    arNginx_url

    db_container = null
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    //report portal dependencies
    implementation 'com.epam.reportportal:commons-model:5.3.3'
    implementation 'com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-logback:5.1.0-RC-1'
    implementation 'org.jf.qa.report-portal:agent-java-spock:5.1.0-RC-4-jf-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.epam.reportportal:client-java:5.1.0-RC-12'
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
}

task reportPortalTask(type: ReportPortalTask) {
    onlyIf {
        (!VersionUtil.isSnapshot(ar_version) && (branch_name.contains("release") || branch_name.contains("master"))) || send_report
    }

    doFirst {
        HashMap<String,String> attributesMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
        String projectName = project.name + test_scope == "BC" ? "-bc" : ""
        String preReleaseVersion = VersionUtil.getPreReleaseVersion(ar_version)
        String launchName = "${projectName}_${preReleaseVersion}_${spec}"

        attributesMap.put("launch_name", launchName)
        attributesMap.put("project_name", projectName)
        attributesMap.put("test_scope", test_scope)
        attributesMap.put("ar_version", ar_version)
        attributesMap.put("ar_type", ar_type)
        attributesMap.put("build_number", "build-$build_number")
        attributesMap.put("preReleaseVersion", preReleaseVersion)
        if(build_url != ""){
            attributesMap.put("build_url", build_url)
        }

        attributesMap.put("group", "core")
        attributesMap.put("spec", spec)
        attributesMap.put("ci_type", ci_type)
        attributesMap.put("data_base", database)
        attributesMap.put("branch_name", "preRelease/f-$preReleaseVersion-rc")

        setAttributesMap(attributesMap)
        setPropertyFilePath(projectDir.toString() + "/src/test/resources/reportportal.properties")
        setLaunchName(launchName)
    }
}

task startar(type: StartarTask) {
    System.setProperty("project_name", project.name)
    System.setProperty("build_directory", project.getBuildDir().path)
    setarVersion(ar_version)
    setpr1Version(pr1_ar_version)
    setpr2Version(pr2_ar_version)
    setHaVersion(ha_ar_version)
    setDbType(database)
    setFederationApproach(federationApproach)
}

task deleteContainers(type: DeleteContainersTask) {
    setDockerUrl(dockerUrl)

    doFirst {
        List<String> containerNames = createarContainerNames()
        containerNames.add(project.ext.arNginx_container)
        containerNames.add(project.ext.db_container)
        setarContainerNames(containerNames)
    }
}

task collectLogs(type: CollectLogsTask) {
    setDockerUrl(dockerUrl)
    setatp(ar_type)
    setSpec(spec)

    doFirst {
        List<String> arContainerNames = createarContainerNames()
        setarContainerNames(arContainerNames)
        List<String> arUrls = createarUrls()
        setarUrls(arUrls)
    }
}

collectLogs.shouldRunAfter(test)
deleteContainers.shouldRunAfter(collectLogs)

tasks.withType(Test) {

    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
    }

    systemProperty "ar_ADMIN_PASSWORD", arAdminPassword
    systemProperty "arpr1_URL", arpr1_url
    systemProperty "arpr2_URL", arpr2_url
    systemProperty "arHaMaster_URL", arHaMaster_url
    systemProperty "arHaSlave_URL", arHaSlave_url
    systemProperty "ar_NGINX_URL", arNginx_url
    systemProperty "ar_TYPE", ar_type
    systemProperty "ar_VERSION", ar_version
    systemProperty "database", database
    systemProperty "build_directory", buildDir
    systemProperty 'DOCKER_REGISTRY', dockerRegistry
    systemProperty 'DOCKER_URL', dockerUrl

    doFirst {
        systemProperty "arpr1_url", project.ext.arpr1_url ?: getProp("arpr1_url")
        systemProperty "arpr2_url", project.ext.arpr2_url ?: getProp("arpr2_url")
        systemProperty "arHaMaster_url", project.ext.arHaMaster_url ?: getProp("arHaMaster_url")
        systemProperty "arHaSlave_url", project.ext.arHaSlave_url ?: getProp("arHaSlave_url")
        systemProperty "platform_url_pr1", project.ext.platform_url_pr1 ?: getProp("platform_url_pr1")
        systemProperty "platform_url_pr2", project.ext.platform_url_pr2 ?: getProp("platform_url_pr2")
        systemProperty "platform_url_ha", project.ext.platform_url_ha ?: getProp("platform_url_ha")
        systemProperty "arNginx_url", project.ext.arNginx_url ?: getProp("arNginx_url")
        systemProperty 'arpr1_container', project.ext.arpr1_container ?: getProp("arpr1_container")
        systemProperty 'arpr2_container', project.ext.arpr2_container ?: getProp("arpr2_container")
        systemProperty 'arHaMaster_container', project.ext.arHaMaster_container ?: getProp("arHaMaster_container")
        systemProperty 'arHaSlave_container', project.ext.arHaSlave_container ?: getProp("arHaSlave_container")
        systemProperty 'arNginx_container', project.ext.arNginx_container ?: getProp("arNginx_container")
        systemProperty 'db_container', project.ext.db_container ?: getProp("db_container")
        systemProperty 'federation_approach', project.federation_approach ?: getProp("federation_approach")
        systemProperty 'debug_logs', project.debug_logs ?: getProp("debug_logs")
    }

    ignoreFailures = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER') != null
}

private String getProp(String prop) {
    if (System.getProperty(prop)) {
        return System.getProperty(prop)
    } else if (System.getenv(prop)) {
        return System.getenv(prop)
    } else {
        return project.getProperties()[prop]
    }
}

private List<String> createarContainerNames() {
    List<String> arContainerNames = []
    arContainerNames.add(project.ext.arpr1_container)
    arContainerNames.add(project.ext.arpr2_container)
    arContainerNames.add(project.ext.arHaMaster_container)
    arContainerNames.add(project.ext.arHaSlave_container)
    return arContainerNames
}

private List<String> createarUrls() {
    List<String> arUrls = []
    arUrls.add(project.ext.arpr1_url)
    arUrls.add(project.ext.arpr2_url)
    arUrls.add(project.ext.arHaMaster_url)
    arUrls.add(project.ext.arHaSlave_url)
    return arUrls
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73644776/2145769

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using VsCode and would recommend to stick with IntelliJ for development. That being said here is what I can tell you.

Spock classes are not main classes, you need to either use JUnit's [console launcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-other), or better delegate to Gradle to run the test. The commandline should look like this `./gradlew test --tests spock.TestSpec`

Unfortunately, Spock doesn't seem to be supported by the [Test Runner for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test) extension. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/425).